# How can i change the position of label of a node in an electric cricuit?

Tags: overleaf, circuitikz, circuits

I've been struggling trying to place the letters *a, b* and *c* on this circuit right at the right side of them, not above or below. Thing is that if i change my code to be at the sides, it will place it over the wire, just like this:

[image]

And this is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}

\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \draw (0,0) to[sV] (0,-2) to[short, -o] node[right]{$c$} (3,-2);
    \draw (0,0) to[sV] (0,2) to[short, -o] node[right]{$a$} (3,2);
    \draw (0,0) to[sV, -o] node[right]{$b$} (3,0);
    
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I don't know what else to do and would appreciate a bit of help ;)

Comment: Please, add a complete **Minimal Working Example**: documentclass and necessary packages as well as `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Done! its now a standalone document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using something like this:

`(coord1) to[...] node[...] {contents} (coord2)`

This draws a path component from `(coord1)` to `(coord2)` and places the specified node somewhere on this subpath, by default at `pos=0.5` (i.e., halfway; `midway` is a synonym of `pos=0.5`). Normally, `pos=0` means “starting point of subpath”, `pos=1` means “end point of subpath” and other values are interpolated.

In your example, position `pos=0` yields somewhat surprising results for me, but it uses the `sV` and `short` keys from `circuitikz` in the `to` options, which certainly explains this—I have no experience with `circuitikz`, sorry. That being said, `pos=1` appears to be the position you are looking for, in all three cases:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to[sV] (0,-2) to[short, -o] node[pos=1, right]{$c$} (3,-2);
\draw (0,0) to[sV] (0,2) to[short, -o] node[pos=1, right]{$a$} (3,2);
\draw (0,0) to[sV, -o] node[pos=1, right]{$b$} (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For nicer output, I propose to fine-tune the label placement using `outer xsep=0.7ex` to adjust the horizontal positions and `anchor=mid west` for better vertical positioning of especially the `b`, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[outer xsep=0.7ex]
\draw (0,0) to[sV] (0,-2) to[short, -o] node[pos=1, anchor=mid west]{$c$} (3,-2);
\draw (0,0) to[sV] (0,2) to[short, -o] node[pos=1, anchor=mid west]{$a$} (3,2);
\draw (0,0) to[sV, -o] node[pos=1, anchor=mid west]{$b$} (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked just finee!! Thank you soo so much :) I knew i had use node[pos=1, right]{$b$} before but didn't remember it

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear it helped!

Comment: @frougon the surprising `pos=0` is because a `circuitikz` `to` does the following: position a node with the component in the center of the path with the correct rotation, then create a sub path from the first coordinate to the left anchor of the component, then another one from the right anchor to the second coordinate. So `pos` is not referred to the full semi path anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it. I used a `\coordinate` for the lower right connector, just to reduce noise a little. Finally I put a `\node` at said coordinate with a distinct label, using the `[yshift]` option. The paranthesis `()` refer the coordinate and prevent introducing a new one. Certainly you could have used math mode here: `$c-label$`.

You could also manipulate the numerical values directly, which is more a matter of preference. You could also use `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`, which allows for relative positioning.

In a nutshell you can use any tikz-command together with this circuit library. Please see the pgf-manual for more choices.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}%, tkz-euclide}% not needed for this purpose
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \draw (0,0) to[sV] (0,-2) to[short, -o] node[right]{$c$} (3,-2);
    \draw (0,0) to[sV] (0,2) to[short, -o] node[right]{$a$} (3,2);
    \draw (0,0) to[sV, -o] node[right]{$b$} (3,0);
    
    
    \end{tikzpicture}


\tikz {% one way to do it
    \coordinate (c) at (3, -2);% coordinates name is "c"
    
    \draw (0,0) to[sV] (0,-2) to[short, -o]  (c);%(c) references coordinate c
    \node [yshift=3mm] at (c) {c-label};% put a lable above, named "c-label"
}


\end{document}
```